# sort json response on click and display accordingly in titanium

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

Hi I have json response which looks like this.

```
{
"id": "7",
"issue_title": "Apr - May 2015",
"issue_no": "Issue 1.4",
"cover_image_url": "http://www.link.org/apr--may-2015-7.jpg",
"synopsis_pdf_url": "",
"advertisers_pdf_url": "",
"issue_date": "01-04-2015",
"issue_year": "2015" 
},
{
"id": "3",
"issue_title": "Feb-Mar 2015",
"issue_no": "Issue 1.3",
"cover_image_url": "http://www.link.org/febmar-2015-3.jpg",
"synopsis_pdf_url": "http://www.link.org/febmar-2015-3.pdf",
"advertisers_pdf_url": "http://www.link.org/febmar-2015-3.pdf",
"issue_date": "01-02-2015",
"issue_year": "2015"
},
{
"id": "2",
"issue_title": "Dec 2014 - Jan 2015",
"issue_no": "Issue 1.2",
"cover_image_url": "http://www.link.org/dec-2014--jan-2015-2.jpg",
"synopsis_pdf_url": "",
"advertisers_pdf_url": "",
"issue_date": "01-12-2014",
"issue_year": "2014"
},
{
"id": "1",
"issue_title": "Oct - Nov 2014",
"issue_no": "Issue 1.1",
"cover_image_url": "http://www.link.org/oct--nov-2014-1.jpg",
"synopsis_pdf_url": "",
"advertisers_pdf_url": "",
"issue_date": "01-10-2014",
"issue_year": "2014"
}
```

Then I retrieved "issue_year" of each element and displayed in picker with multiple occurrence deleted.

Basically when the window loads all the elements are displayed but after that on a click of picker element (i.e 2014 ,2015 ) the elements should get display.

Tableview is used for displaying elements so on each click the array passed to tableview should get change according to year selected from picker.

```
var i,
len = singleData.length,
sorted = [],
obj = {};

for ( i = 0; i < len; i++) {
obj[singleData[i]] = 0;
}
for (i in obj) {
sorted.push(i);
}

for (var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
    data[i] = Ti.UI.createPickerRow({
    title : sorted[i]
}); 
}

$.picker.add(data);

$.picker.addEventListener('change',function(e){
//what will be the code here
});
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Do you need help in how to pass the data to table view, or for sorting the json ?

Comment: if `issue_year` is selected as 2014...then only records having year as 2014 are to passed to tableview

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple. here's what you need to do:

Add a custom property to your picker, containing the obj to be sent:

```
for (var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
    data[i] = Ti.UI.createPickerRow({
    title : sorted[i],
    obj: MY_OBJ // HERE YOU NEED TO PASS THE OBJECT THAT WILL BE SENT TO DISPLAY
}); 
}
```

Next, in your listener, you can access that object using:

```
$.picker.addEventListener('change',function(e){
  alert(e.source.obj); // This will alert the correct object you created in the picker!
});
```

Hope it helps! 
-Lucas

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
 data[i] = Ti.UI.createPickerRow({
  title : sorted[i],
  obj :args[i]
  
 });
}`
If we consider the above code i.e args array is the whole json response which I posted above and if I give this to obj then obviously it will not be helpful.
Basically I want if we are selecting 2014 then the elements having 2014 as the issue_year should come as a unit so that I can pass that aaray to tableview.
custom property will not meet up the requirement I guess :-)

Comment: Actually it will. Create a separate function that maps a year into an array, for example, and pass that array as a custom obj.

So something like:

     for (var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) { data[i] = Ti.UI.createPickerRow({ title : sorted[i], obj :map_tparray(sorted[i]) }); }

Comment: @LucasA..I dont want array of years...title is taking care of that..sorted array consists of years (i.e 2014,2015)...from your suggestion it seems like there is no difference between title and obj both will contain years only.what I have to do if I select 2015..I should get the whole element of json response which has 2015 as issue year(i.e filter json response by year) mentioned in question.I want WHOLE ELEMENT. :-)

Comment: @Bunny Im not saying you should have an array of years by itself. You should have an array of objects, that map a key to the year and another obj inside of it, containing the WHOLE ELEMENT. To do that, you will need to map to a obj, all the JSON objs that are related to that year - do that for each year.